# Express Routes in Parse Cloud Code Module

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

I am using parse.com cloud code with express to setup my routes.  I have done this in the past with node, and I have my routes in separate files. So, in node I do

app.js

```
express = require("express"); 
app = exports.app = express();
require("./routes/js/account");
```

account.js

```
app = module.parent.exports.app;
app.get("/api/account/twitter", passport.authenticate("twitter"));
```

All the examples on parses site https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webapp show this being done as follows.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.render('hello', { message: 'Congrats, you just set up your app!' });
});
```

So, I would like to change the bottom to include a routes folder with separate routes files, but am not sure how to do this in parse.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is a little old, but I just wanted to post a solution for anyone still looking to get this to work.

What you need to do, is create your route file, I keep them in 'routes' forlder,  for example `<my_app_dir>/cloud/routes/user.js`

Inside user.js you will have something that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

   app.get("/users/login", function(req, res) {
      .. do your custom logic here ..
   });

   app.get("/users/logout", function(req, res) {
      .. do your custom logic here ..
   });
}
```

Then, in app.js you just include your file, but remember that you need to append `cloud` to the path, and pass the reference to your app instance:

```
require('cloud/routes/user')(app);
```

Also, remember that express evaluates routes in order, so you should take that into consideration when importing several route files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a different method, have the routes in app.js, but you can probably include them in file if you prefer. Take a look at the example app, 
[anyblog on github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyBlog/blob/master/cloud/app.js)

The way it works:

Set up a controller:

```
// Controller code in separate files.
var postsController = require('cloud/controllers/posts.js');
```

Add the controller route

```
// Show all posts on homepage
app.get('/', postsController.index);

// RESTful routes for the blog post object.
app.get('/posts', postsController.index);
app.get('/posts/new', postsController.new);
```

And then in [posts.js](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyBlog/blob/master/cloud/controllers/posts.js), you can use exports, ex.

```
var Post = Parse.Object.extend('Post');

// Display all posts.
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
  query.descending('createdAt');
  query.find().then(function(results) {
    res.render('posts/index', { 
      posts: results
    });
  },
  function() {
    res.send(500, 'Failed loading posts');
  });
};

// Display a form for creating a new post.
exports.new = function(req, res) {
  res.render('posts/new', {});
};
```

Comment: Yea, I like this method.  But I would still like to move my routes out of the app.js file, as I will have a ton of them, and each will have at least a little bit of code that might call the controllers with callbacks.  SO, I want to have the app.get's in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the app reference to the post controller, and add the routes from there